# If $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^2$ then $(\lambda_{n+1}^2 + |\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_n|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^2$, ie $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|\lambda_n|^2<\infty$. Consider the sequence $(\lambda_n^2 + |\lambda_{n-1}-\lambda_n|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. I wan to show that $(\lambda_{n+1}^2 + |\lambda_{n}-\lambda_{n+1}|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^1$. My attempt is as follows:

$\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|\lambda_{n+1}^2 + |\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_n|| = \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n+1}^2 + |\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_n| =\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n+1}^2 + \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_n|\leq \sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\lambda_{n+1}^2+\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|\lambda_{n+1}|+\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|\lambda_{n}|<\infty$

Since $(\lambda_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^2\supset\ell^1$ and so each of the three sums above is finite.

Comment: The series $\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb N} |\lambda_n|$ diverges for $\lambda\in \ell^2\setminus\ell^1$. You claim is indeed wrong: Consider $\lambda\in\ell^2\setminus\ell^1$ with $\lambda_{2n}=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: You're right. What if I impose the condition that $\lambda_n$ is a nonincreasing sequence?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is decreasing you have $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N|\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_n|=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N(\lambda_{n}-\lambda_{n+1})=\lambda_1-\lambda_{N+1} \to \lambda_1$ because every sequence in $\ell^2$ tends to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $ \lambda_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, then $\lambda_n^2 + |\lambda_{n-1}-\lambda_n| \ge \frac{1}{n}$. hence

$(\lambda_{n+1}^2 + |\lambda_{n}-\lambda_{n+1}|)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\notin\ell^1$.